# How to get value from DatePicker

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I'm trying to work with datepicker from jquery, but I don't know, how to get a value from it.

I'm using this code for datepicker view:

```
JQ.DatePicker = Em.View.extend(JQ.Widget, {
 uiType: 'datepicker',
 uiOptions: ['disabled', 'altField', 'altFormat', 'appendText', 'autoSize', 'buttonImage', 'buttonImageOnly', 'buttonText', 'calculateWeek', 'changeMonth', 'changeYear', 'closeText', 'constrainInput', 'currentText', 'dateFormat', 'dayNames', 'dayNamesMin', 'dayNamesShort', 'defaultDate', 'duration', 'firstDay', 'gotoCurrent', 'hideIfNoPrevNext', 'isRTL', 'maxDate', 'minDate', 'monthNames', 'monthNamesShort', 'navigationAsDateFormat', 'nextText', 'numberOfMonths', 'prevText', 'selectOtherMonths', 'shortYearCutoff', 'showAnim', 'showButtonPanel', 'showCurrentAtPos', 'showMonthAfterYear', 'showOn', 'showOptions', 'showOtherMonths', 'showWeek', 'stepMonths', 'weekHeader', 'yearRange', 'yearSuffix'],
 uiEvents: ['create', 'beforeShow', 'beforeShowDay', 'onChangeMonthYear', 'onClose', 'onSelect'],
 tagName: 'input',
 type: "text",
 attributeBindings: ['type', 'value']
});
```

And my extended view:

```
App.DatePicker = JQ.DatePicker.extend({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      classNames: ['form-control'],
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        this.value = dateText;
        this.set('value',dateText);
      }
    });
```

at html page I added:

```
{{#view App.DatePicker valueBinding="date"}}{{/view}}
```

My controller:

```
App.MainController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    templateName: "main",
    date: null,

    saveDate: function(value){
        console.log("saveDate");
        this.date = value;
    },  

    showData: function(){
        alert(this.date);
    },

});
```

I tested some other options in {{view App.DatePicker }}, but I don't understand how these view and controller work. Can somebody help me with this code or send me some link to a nice guide concerning this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have figured it out.

add attributeBindings: ["value"] to App.DatePicker:

```
App.DatePicker = JQ.DatePicker.extend({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      classNames: ['form-control'],
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        this.value = dateText;
        this.set('value',dateText);
      },

      attributeBindings: ["value"]

    });
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer, so that it does not appear in the "Unanswered" questions list for Ember. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var date = $('#date').datepicker('getDate');
```

Documentation:
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate